# Persist alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true; in Oracle 12c

Tags: docker, oracle

I have an oracle 12c (1.0.2) running in Docker. 
I'm using a script which is executed during container startup:

```
TESTER IDENTIFIED BY TESTER;
```

This fails with [this error](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_65096_create_user_12c_without_c_prefix.htm):

```
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
```

When I alter my script it works fine:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
TESTER IDENTIFIED BY TESTER;
```

But I don't want to add this to every script. Is there a way you can persist this setting in the database?

Also in [this doc](https://dzone.com/articles/oracle-12c-image-installation-in-docker?utm_medium=feed&utm_source=feedpress.me&utm_campaign=Feed:%20dzone) they need to alter the session.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write this setting permanently by writing :

```
alter system set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

see Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/changing-parameter-values-in-a-parameter-file.html#GUID-4C578B21-DE2B-4210-8EB7-EF28D36CC1CB)

Comment: Have you try this? This doesn't even affect the current session.. How could it work for any other session opened in future?